# How to select single Integer value from a String?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

So I have a string X = '03456789'
And another string Y = '12809009'

If the first two integers in my variable are 03 like in X, I want to be able to store them as a single value (3) .. and if first two integers are like 12, I want to store them as (12). How can I achieve that in Javascript.

Comment: substr and parseInt....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
+X.slice(0,2)
```

In javascript a string is an array of characters. So you use the slice function to select the first two elements. The `+` sign will convert the resulting string to a number.

Comment: Perfect. Explained very well and was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Type conversion isn't casting/coercion. It's important to know the difference.

Comment: Thank you, I was in the middle of writing an answer, but this is much more concise and effective!

Comment: @RamishMian - if this is the answer you were looking for, feel free to mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Some questions to think about:

1.  Will the String always be length 8?
2.  If not, what is the most likely reason the length would change?
3.  Will the String always be zero filled?
4.  If not, could 12 really be 012 with the leading zero removed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a highorder function that returns a match.

```js
var y = '0124242';
var x = '2153532';

function getFirstTwo(str) {
  var result = str.match(/^[0-9]{2}/);
  if (result[0][0] === '0') {
    return result[0][1];
  }
  return result[0];
}

console.log(getFirstTwo(x));
```